# change location of autoexec in sas

Tags: sas

Hi I want to change the default location of autoexec on SAS. 
I have an autoexec in the sas root location. But I want to create a new autoexec and let the SAS connect to it instead to the default one. 
How can I do it.

I want to do it because I donot have to adminstrative rights. But I want SAS to connect to the new Autoexec.

Answer (score 3):

When you start SAS, use the `-autoexec` option to specify the location and file.  That will override the value defined by your administrator.

```
>sas ... -autoexec \path\to\file\autoexec.sas
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a %include step in the existing autoexec

```
%inc "/my/new/autoexec/location.sas";
```

Although this would still involve connecting to the default..